# Css issue with mapping the Elemnts

Tags: html, css

In my Website i am mapping the Elements by ID. it is working fine for All the alphabet Letters Except A, But When i click on the alphabet A it is not going to respective Elements please Help me to come out of this. http://dotmappersdesign.com/mclarenpress/glossary/

Comment: Please include your relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code *here*, in your question and provide a clear explanation of your problem; don't just link to your website and expect us to go and luck: help us to help you.

Comment: Even when i try to go to the website my firefox tells me that the page is not trustworthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work. For A, as well as the rest. It's just that there is more than one explanation for the other letters, so the effect is not as obvious. See B for example. The first word for B is "Binding", but the first explanation you see after clicking the letter is for "Binding Margin".

The reason for this is that the link brings the anchor to the top of the screen and does not account for your fixed header, so it gets hidden below that.

A possible CSS-only solution would be a combination of padding and negative margin, to move the elements top border, which will align to the top of the screen, to make up for the height of the header. Here's an example that works on your site, but you should make the selector more specific (`#glossary p strong`, or use the semantically correct [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fdl)).

```
p strong {
    display: inline-block; /* Required for the margin/padding to have an effect */
    margin-top: -60px;
    padding: 60px 0 0;
}
```